# How to access elements stored in a list in the server (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to call the function fziim (defined previously) whose arguments depend on the values of two widgets defined in the ui. The function returns a list with several plots that I want to display.

I try the following code but can't make it run properly, as the elements of the list appear not be accessible

first the ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

  fluidRow(

    column(9,
           selectInput("sector", h4("Sector"), 
                       choices = list("S1","S1")
                       , selected = 1))# need to insrt instead list with sector names
  ),

  fluidRow(

    column(9, 
           numericInput("num1", 
                        h4("Investment value (million $)"), 
                        value = "100"))  
  )
),
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(

    tabPanel("Trade Balance",

             fluidRow(
               plotOutput("graph_trade")
             )

    ),
    tabPanel("Imports",

             fluidRow(
               plotOutput("graph_imports")
             )

    ),
    tabPanel("Exports",

             fluidRow(
               plotOutput("graph_exports")
             )

    ),
    tabPanel("Supply chain",

             fluidRow(
               plotOutput("graph_supply_chain")
             )

    ),
    tabPanel("Taxes",


             fluidRow(
               plotOutput("graph_all_taxes")

             )
    ),

    tabPanel("Employment",

             fluidRow(
               plotOutput("graph_employment"),

             )

    )



  )
)
  )
)
```

And the server is as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  impacts_update<-fziim(sector =input$sector,investment =input$num1 )



  output$graph_all_taxes<-renderPlot({
    impacts_update$graph_all_taxes

  })
  output$graph_employment<-renderPlot({
    impacts_update$graph_employment
  })
  output$graph_trade<-renderPlot({
    impacts_update$graph_trade_balance
  })
  output$graph_imports<-renderPlot({
    impacts_update$graph_imports_blockade
  })
  output$graph_exports<-renderPlot({
    impacts_update$graph_exports_blockade
  })
  output$graph_supply_chain<-renderPlot({
    impacts_update$graph_domestic
  })


}
```

Where fziim looks like:

```
fziim<-function(sector, investment){
  g1<-plot1
  g2<-plot2
  g3<-plot3
  g4<-plot4
  g5<-plot5
  g6<-plot6

  output<-list(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6)
  return(output)
}
```

Comment: please provide more code to reproduce the problem

Comment: `renderPlot` creates a reactive plot that is supposed to be output, so assigning this to a variable does not make much sense as you cannot parse raw data from it.

Comment: @Chabo you are right, the idea is to create impacts-update (a list with six plot elements), and then call them with render plot below

Comment: @PorkChop the code is a large model. The question is more conceptual as to how to access the elements of the list consisting of the output of fziim that react to the choices of the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reproducible app that hits the main points of what you are after. We make the 
`impacts_update` a reactive function and call it in every `renderPlot` function. Doing so allows us to assign it to a regular variable and pull from the list of data.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("A","Test",choices=c(1,2,3)),
    selectInput("B","TEest",choices=c(1,2,3))
    ),


    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("graph_all_taxes"),
      plotOutput("graph_employment")
    )

    ))

      server <- function(input, output) {

        fziim<-function(A,B){
          C<-(1:3)
          A<-as.numeric(A)
          dfA<-data.frame(A,C)
          g1<-dfA
          B<-as.numeric(B)
          dfB<-data.frame(B,C)
          g2<-dfB
          return(list(g1,g2))
        }


        impacts_update<-reactive({
          fziim(input$A, input$B)
        })

        output$graph_all_taxes<-renderPlot({
          graph_tax<-impacts_update()
          graph_tax<-unlist(graph_tax)
          plot(graph_tax[1])
        })
        output$graph_employment<-renderPlot({
          graph_tax2<-impacts_update()
          graph_tax2<-unlist(graph_tax2)
          plot(graph_tax2[2])
        })

        #And so on...


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note: My fiizm function is only for testing purposes.

**Main change**

How we create the list

```
impacts_update<-reactive({
fziim(sector =input$sector,investment =input$num1)
)}
```

How we call the list

```
output$graph_all_taxes<-renderPlot({
          graph_tax<-impacts_update()
          graph_tax<-unlist(graph_tax)
          plot(graph_tax[1])
        })
```